# Reload a div without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to reload a `div` without reloading the whole page for efficiency.

I tried this code:

```
$('#mydiv').load(document.URL +  '#mydiv');
```

but it just reloads my whole page inside my `div`.

I also tried this too:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function (){
    $('#background').load('dashboard.php').fadeIn("slow"); 
}, 1);
```

But neither are very efficient, since I need to refresh in "real time" or the closest to it.

Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Depending on the kind of content of that div, you may not need to reload anything. Can we see your markup?

Comment: You need a space `$('#mydiv').load(document.URL +  ' #mydiv');`

Comment: Are you trying to request/load only partial content from the full page? I don't see how that would work since PHP would still need to execute all the code for that page. Create a specific PHP file/route that only returns the data you want and call that instead.

Comment: i put it on here : https://pastebin.com/P5dHZgXF

I need to update the values that come from php

Answer (score -1):

you could use ajax.

```
$.ajax({

    url : 'dashboard.php',
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(data) {              
       $('body').replaceWith(data);
    }
  
});
```

Comment: .load IS Ajax and OP want to only get the div with ID mydiv